# Is the scope of an oauth2 access token bound to the token or the user?

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0

I'm having a hard time asking the question so let me explain to you our half baked OAuth 2.0 solution:

Currently, we only use a trusted grant, rather we ask for a username and password. If those creds are authenticated successfully, we issue an access token and a refresh token. However, there is no scope information in that response message. The OAuth2 spec says that if a scope is provided in a request, then it needs to be returned in the response as well, but only if the granted scope is different from the requested scope. In any we're not assigning a scope to the toke, only a token that says that the user is validated. This doesn't feel right to me, but maybe I'm over thinking it.

Later on in our flow, the client will attempt to access a protected resource such as logging int to a website that is only granted to a certain role. So while you may be authenticated (you possess an access token), you may not be allowed to log into this site due to your role. The way that we currently validate this is by sending the access token to the resource endpoint. That endpoint then sends the token along with the uri that you're tryin to access to our validation server which validates that your token is good and that your role (which we look up by the token entry in the database)permits you to access the resource, then return a 200 to allow you to continue or a 403 that says you don't have access to that endpoint. So in other words, the access token doesn't have any scope assigned to it directly, rather it just tells us who you are, then we look up your permissions and compare it to the request and say yay or nay. This seem weird to me.

In other implementations that I've seen, I got the impression that it is supposed to actually work like this:

- you request an access token, if your creds are validated successfully
  then a token is generated.
- The auth server then looks at your requested scope, then generates a token in a database along with the approved portion of your
  requested scope (partial or complete). Rather, if you requested a b c
  and d, but only b and d where approved then the token stored in our
  database would reflect that only b and c are permitted with that
  token.
- The token string along with the approved scope is sent back to the client.
- During a protected resource request, we look up the token in the database and compare the requested resource with what is in the scope
  entry for the provided token, then return yay or nay, rather than
  looking up the user permissions.

So what's the difference? I was under the impression that a TOKEN contains the scope. So if user A is allowed resources A B C D and E, but requests B C and F, then the token will only be good for B and C. We don't simple grant A because he is permitted to do so; he didn't ask for A D or E and he is not permitted F so the token does not permit them. Does that make sense?

So my question is this. Is our current implementation wrong based on my understanding of the way it's supposed to be used? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your implementation is not quite complete.  The client app is requesting a resource on behalf of the resource owner.  When the resource server receives a request with an access token, it should check that (1) the token is valid and not expired, (2) the requested resource is within the scope the token was granted for and (3) the resource owner can access the requested resource.

For #1, the authorization server will need to keep track of all tokens and when they expire. For #2, the authorization server will have to remember the scope for each token and be able to relate a particular resource to a scope. The resource server should know how to check #3.

To answer your question "Is the scope of an oauth2 access token bound to the token or the user?", the scope is associated with the token.  The token was issued for a particular scope.